# Why is my Many to Many relationship field undefined?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typeorm

I am trying to create a follower/following system and when I try to append the new user to the following list I get the error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. This ends up creating 2 separate tables one for users following other users and one for users being followed by other users. Not sure why it's not picking up the field? Any help is appreciated.

```
import { Length } from "class-validator";
import {
    Column,
    CreateDateColumn,
    Entity,
    JoinTable,
    ManyToMany,
    OneToMany,
    PrimaryColumn,
    RelationCount,
    Unique,
    UpdateDateColumn
} from "typeorm";

export class User {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    public user_id: string;

    @Column()
    public first_name: string;

    @Column()
    public last_name: string;

    @Column()
    public email: string;

    @Column()
    public phone_number: string;

    @Column()
    public username: string;

    @Column()
    @CreateDateColumn()
    public created_on: Date;

    @Column()
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    public updated_at: Date;

    @ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.following)
    @JoinTable()
    public followers: User[];

    @ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.followers)
    @JoinTable()
    public following: User[];

    @RelationCount((user: User) => user.followers)
    public followers_count: number;

    @RelationCount((user: User) => user.following)
    public following_count: number;
}
```

```
const { user_id, 
        follow_user_id } = req.
const user_repo = getRepository(User);
const user = await user_repo.findOne({
    where: {user_id}
});
const follow_user = new User();

follow_user.user_id = follow_user_id;
user.following.push(follow_user);
const result = user_repo.save(user);
```

Error is referring to this line `user.following.push(follow_user);`

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't test ways below, but think one of them should help you.

**1st way.** At your `User` class.

```js
    // Source code omission
    @ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.followers)
    @JoinTable()
    public following: User[] = []; // ★ Added assign
    // Source code omission
```

**2nd way.** At your `User` class.

```js
export class User {
    // Source code omission
    constructor() { // ★ Added line
        this.following = []; // ★ Added line
    } // ★ Added line
}
```

**3rd way.** At place where you use `User` class.

```js
const follow_user = new User();

follow_user.user_id = follow_user_id;
user.following = []; // ★ Added line
user.following.push(follow_user);
const result = user_repo.save(user);
```

**4th way.** At place where you use `User` class.

```js
const follow_user = new User();

follow_user.user_id = follow_user_id;
user.following = [follow_user]; // ★ Edited line
const result = user_repo.save(user);
```

Comment: The first way is invalid I get the error `Error: Array initializations are not allowed in entity relations. Please remove array initialization (= [])`. The 2nd option resulted in the same result. The 3rd option did work.

Comment: Maybe 4th way you’d like more.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered a similar error with OneToMany and ManyToOne relations where the relative returned null/undefined.

The workaround I'm using involves putting this in the User class:

```
  @AfterLoad()
  async nullChecks() {
    if (!this.followers) {
      this.followers = []
    }

    if (!this.following) {
      this.following = []
    }
  }
```

[documentation](https://www.bookstack.cn/read/TypeORM/listeners-and-subscribers.md)

Comment: This works for fetching existing entries, but not when creating a new entry with `new MyClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

We use this approach to avoid undefined lists:

```
@ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.following)
@JoinTable()
private _followers: User[];
```

...

```
get followers() : User[] {
  if (!_followers) {
    _followers = [];
  }
  return _followers;
}
```